# Find Similarity Of Two Hand Sign Images OpenCv

Tags: java, image-processing, android, opencv

I am Working on Sign Translator Application For Handy People. In My application User Will Give one sign image from camera or gallery given image will be compare with database images and show the result With Alphabetic Sign.

but my problem is i am not getting good similarity between two images Some Time result is accurate some time not.
Please Refer me Some Idea Or source Code.
Thanks in advance.

```
 Scalar lowerThreshold =  new Scalar(0, 48, 80); // Blue color – lower hsv values
    Scalar upperThreshold = new Scalar(20, 255, 255); // Blue color – higher hsv values

    FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.PYRAMID_FAST);
    DescriptorExtractor extractor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.ORB);

    //orb orb bruteforce with filter method
    DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING);
    //crash on surf flanbased


    Mat img1 = new Mat();
    Mat img2 = new Mat();


    Utils.bitmapToMat(defaultImage,img1);
    Utils.bitmapToMat(databaseImage,img2);



    Mat descriptors1 = new Mat();
    MatOfKeyPoint keypoints1 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    detector.detect(img1, keypoints1);
    extractor.compute(img1, keypoints1, descriptors1);


    //second image

    Mat descriptors2 = new Mat();
    MatOfKeyPoint keypoints2 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    detector.detect(img2, keypoints2);
    extractor.compute(img2, keypoints2, descriptors2);


    //matcher image descriptors
    MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();
    matcher.match(descriptors1,descriptors2,matches);

    //Filter matches by distance
    MatOfDMatch filtered = filterMatchesByDistance(matches);

    int total = (int) matches.size().height;
    int Match= (int) filtered.size().height;
    Log.d("LOG", "total:" + total + " Match:"+Match);

    int percent = (int)((Match * 100.0f) / total);
    if(percent>max){
        max=percent;
        maximumPercentage.setMaximum(percent);
        maximumPercentage.setImageId(id);
        imageId=id;
        Log.d("Maximum Percentage: ",String.valueOf(max)+"%");
        Log.d("MaxId: ",String.valueOf(imageId));
    }
    id++;
    Log.d("matchingOImages: ",String.valueOf(percent)+"%");
```

filter matching result method

```
 List<DMatch> matches_original = matches.toList();
    List<DMatch> matches_filtered = new ArrayList<DMatch>();

    int DIST_LIMIT = 30;
    // Check all the matches distance and if it passes add to list of filtered matches
    Log.d("DISTFILTER", "ORG SIZE:" + matches_original.size() + "");
    for (int i = 0; i < matches_original.size(); i++) {
        DMatch d = matches_original.get(i);
        if (Math.abs(d.distance) <= DIST_LIMIT) {
            matches_filtered.add(d);
        }
    }
    Log.d("DISTFILTER", "FIL SIZE:" + matches_filtered.size() + "");

    MatOfDMatch mat = new MatOfDMatch();
    mat.fromList(matches_filtered);
    return mat;
```

Comment: What you are asking is at the fringe of current state of the art. Ordinary keypoint matching will never work. Try your luck with deep learning.

Comment: which approach i have to use can u provide me some links or topic detail

Comment: This is not a problem that can be solved "in a single click". Read about deep learning.

Answer (score 0):

Ok well i think you just entered the modern age of neural networks.
As it can be overwhelming how this stuff works, and often takes years of study, there are some shortcuts to get things done.

For the quickest result I think you might start here:
 ( Assuming you rather dont want to dive that deep into the innerworkings of a neural net, but rather would use existing software, or services ) https://cloud.google.com/automl/

Comment: do u have any links on opencv i have to do this task with opencv

Comment: OpenCV is as far as i know not a neural network framework.
You will have to combine OpenCV width some neural network framework then.